# Convert a decimal string to a signed 2's complement binary integer

Tags: assembly, input, x86

I was just wondering what the code would be to convert a decimal integer (entered in by the user) to a 2's compliment representation in memory.

Example: the user enters 1234 as the decimal. I want to store 04D2 (the binary 2's complement representation) in AX (since I'm only allowed to use word length strings)

I'm using 80x86 architecture.

Comment: Um, 04d2 isn't two's complement. It is just the number 1234 in hexadecimal notation. Are you trying to parse a string to an integer?

Comment: well my ultimate goal is to get a 16bit number from the user convert it to 2's compliment and then find its octal representation. I

Comment: Do you need to handle negative integers too, or just positive integers?

Comment: negative integers as well. I've been given two examples. 
1234's octal representation is 004 322.
-1's octal representation is 377 377. I understand why and how they got the octal representations, I just need the intermediate step on how they got 04D2 from 1234 in code.

Comment: Pseudocode, works for kbds with an ASCII char set.  You get to figure out the positive or negative logic as it will get too cramped here. :) `result = 0; while( (c = kbdRead) != '\n') { result *= 10; result += c - '0'` (Note: Off the top of my head...) Also note a negative number in 2's complement has the MSB set.

Comment: The octal representation of (16-bit) -1 is 177777, you'll get mighty confused if you try to make it 377377.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting a string of digits to an integer is mostly fairly simple: you read one digit at a time, convert that to a decimal number (normally by subtracting '0' from it). You take your existing value, multiply it by ten, and add the value of the current digit.

Dealing with negative numbers adds just a bit more difficulty to that. Most people do it by keeping a flag to indicate the number is negative if it starts with a '-'. Then, when they've converted the number, they negate if if that flag is set.

That does, however, have one problem: converting the most negative number takes some extra work, because (in 2's complement) the most negative number has a larger magnitude than you can represent as a positive number (without using more bits). For example, 16-bit 2's complement numbers range from -32768 to +32767, but you need either (at least) 17 bits or an unsigned 16-bit number to represent +32768.

Edit: Once you've converted the decimal digits to an integer, you'll need to convert the integer to hexadecimal digits to display it in hex. That conversion is a little bit easier. You repeatedly divide by 16 and the remainder becomes the next hexadecimal digit. You'll normally use a table like "0123456789abcdef" and use that remainder to index into the table to get the digit for display. You repeat the division and using the remainder until your dividend is zero. The one trick is that this produces the digits in *reverse* order (from least to most significant), so you normally put them into a buffer, starting from the end of the buffer and working your way toward the beginning.

Comment: I guess What I'm asking is when the user inputs a number, how can I see the hexidecimal value for it.

Comment: @cj1098: you have to convert from decimal digits into an integer. Then you have to convert from the integer to hexadecimal digits.

Comment: @cj1098: For the unsigned string of ASCII decimal digits->binary integer (without the leading-- handling), see [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](//stackoverflow.com/a/49548057) for the `total = total*10 + new_digit` algorithm. (Also see the "multi-digit number" section of [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)). To see a register value (binary integer) as hex, use a debugger to display it in hex. Or use a calculator.

Answer (score -2):

It takes notting the bits,  and then adding 1...  but thats only if you know if its positive.
If its negative you have to take 1, then not it,  the reverse operation.  it should be 2 cycles to do it.

Comment: `neg eax` is a single-uop instruction with 1 cycle latency (it works by subtracting from 0, which is the same thing as `not eax; inc eax` because x86 is a 2's complement ISA).  Use that if you want 2's complement **negation**.  But that's not actually what this question is asking: it's asking how to convert a (signed) string of decimal digits to a signed integer.

Comment: re: cycles: see https://agner.org/optimize/ for how performance works on modern x86 microarchitectures.  Latency and throughput are separate things.  Also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for more links.